# shutil.copy fails after os.makedirs

Tags: python-3.x, database, error-handling, backup, shutil

so as you can see im trying to create a small backup script for my self, to  select needed files and back them up.

```
import shutil
import datetime
import os
import time
def backup():
    # set the update interval
    while True:
        backup_interval = input("Please enter the backup interval in seconds: ") # 300
        try:
            valid_time = int(backup_interval) // 60
            print("Backup time set to:", valid_time, "minutes!")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("This time is not valid, please enter a correct time in seconds: ")
            print(">>> 60 seconds = 1 minute, 3600 seconds = 60 minutes.")

    backup_file = input(r"Please enter the path for the file to backup: ") # D:\Python\BackupDB\test.db"
    dest_dir = input(r"Please enter the destination path: ") # D:\Python\BackupDB\
    folder_name = input(r"Please name your backup folder: ") # BD_Backup
    now = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19]
    now = now.replace(":", "_")
    # backup_file = backup_file.replace(backup_file, backup_file + str(now) + ".db")
    # thats why I got the FileNotFoundError
    final_destination = os.path.join(dest_dir, folder_name)
    if not os.path.exists(final_destination):
        os.makedirs(final_destination)

    print("hello world")
    shutil.copy(backup_file, final_destination)
```

the first question is, how do i replace the name after i copied the file into the destination folder to get something like that test.db -> test_2020-02-23 08_36_22.db
like here :

```
source_dir = r"D:\Python\BackupDB\test.db"
destination_dir = r"D:\Python\BackupDB\BD_Backup\test_" + str(now) + ".db"
shutil.copy(source_dir, destination_dir)
```

output :

```
test_2020-02-23 08_36_22.db
```

what im doing wrong here?
and how to copy the file 5 times and after a while (backup_interval) delete the first one and move the last 4 up and create a new one so I have in total 5 copies of that file?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code as you need,

```
        backup_file = input(r"Please enter the path for the file to backup: ") # D:\Python\BackupDB\test.db"
        dest_dir = input(r"Please enter the destination path: ") # D:\Python\BackupDB\
        folder_name = input(r"Please name your backup folder: ") # BD_Backup
        old_file_name=backup_file.split("/")[-1]
        now = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:19]
        now = now.replace(":", "_")
        new_file_name = old_file_name.split(".")[0]+"_" + str(now) + ".db"
        final_destination = os.path.join(dest_dir, folder_name)
        if not os.path.exists(final_destination):
            os.mkdir(final_destination)
        new_file="/"+new_file_name
        shutil.copy(backup_file, final_destination)
        os.rename(final_destination+'/'+old_file_name,final_destination+new_file)
```

I did like , after copy the file, i just rename it

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into a similar problem before and the reason was that the creation of the directory hadn't completed yet before trying to access it. A simple sleep before the copy should be able to confirm this.

Comment: well I also tought about that but python does line for line.
so the problem was here:
backup_file = backup_file.replace(backup_file, backup_file + str(now) + ".db")
i changed the file i was trying to copy :D